# Questions about the SQUID (Superconducting Quantum Interference Device)

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, quantum-computer, inductance, josephson-junction

1. If the bias current is approximately 2 Ic (double the critical current), wouldn’t the whole loop become normal? Or do only the Josephson junctions become normal? And when the junctions become resistive, how can you even have Cooper pairs (and thus have the loop be superconducting)? Is it because the bias current is below 2 delta (energy needed to break Cooper pairs) but still above Ic? Would that mean that the SQUID have both Cooper pairs and quasiparticles when a bias current is applied?
2. Why even have Josephson junctions in a SQUID? I’m relatively new to trying to learn about the SQUID so my impression so far is that it seems to rely mostly on the loop being superconducting. The main distinction with the junctions are the associated phases but I’m struggling to understand why this is necessary when the SQUID relies on the voltage changing with trying to keep an integer value of the magnetic flux.

Answer (score 1):

There is an (understandable) confusion here stemming from the fact that "critical current" gets used in a number of completely different, yet superconductor-adjacent ways. The important thing to recognize from the beginning is that when you exceed the critical current of a JJ, nothing goes from a superconducting state to a normal state; it is completely different from the critical current of a superconductor.

**Voltage-biased JJ's**

Consider for a moment the phenomenology of a JJ, which we'll take to consist of two superconductors with an insulating barrier in between them. If we apply a constant voltage $V$ across the JJ, then the *current* through the JJ is found to be

$$I = \alpha V + \beta \sin(\omega_J t+\varphi_0)\tag{1}$$

where $\omega_J \equiv 2eV/\hbar$ is the *Josephson frequency*, and $\varphi_0 $ is some phase offset. The first term corresponds to the flow of normal electrons across the junction, while the second term corresponds to the flow of Cooper pairs across the junction. We identify the constant $\alpha \equiv 1/R$ as the normal conductance of the junction, while the constant $\beta\equiv I_c$ is called the *critical current* of the junction.

To model this scenario, we consider an ideal JJ (with infinite normal resistance) in parallel with an ordinary resistor.
[image]

This is called the *resistively shunted junction* model, or RSJ. As per the diagram, the ideal JJ is characterized by its critical current, just as the resistor is characterized by its resistance. The relevant equations governing this model are the following:
$$I = \frac{V}{R} + I_c \sin(\varphi)\tag{2}$$
$$\frac{d\varphi}{dt} = \frac{2eV}{\hbar}\tag{3}$$
Equation $(2)$ says that the total current through is equal to the sum of the current through the resistor and the current through the junction, where the latter is given by $I_c\sin(\varphi)$. The phase $\varphi$ is really the phase *difference* between the superconducting order parameters on either side of the junction, which we recall are complex numbers.

The identification of the current through the JJ as being of the form $I_c\sin(\varphi)$ is called the first Josephson equation. Equation $(3)$ is the *second* Josephson equation, which says that the rate of change of the phase across the junction is proportional to the voltage across it. Taking $V$ to be constant, we see trivially that $\phi = \frac{2eV}{\hbar}t + \phi_0$, and we immediately obtain $(1)$. So voltage-biased JJ's are relatively straightforward.

**Current-biased JJ's**

*Current*-biased JJ's are a bit more subtle. Before proceeding, let's plug $(3)$ into $(2)$ to obtain

$$\frac{\hbar}{2eR}\varphi' + I_c\sin(\varphi)-I = 0$$

If $I\leq I_c$, then the steady-state solution to this equation is simply $\varphi = \sin^{-1}(I/I_c)$. If $\varphi$ is different from this value at $t=0$, then a transient voltage will develop which allows $\varphi$ to adjust to its steady-state value, at which point the phase becomes locked in place and the voltage disappears. To summarize, an RSJ which is current-biased below $I_c$ has no current flowing through the resistor and a steady supercurrent flowing through the junction.

If $I>I_c$, the behavior of the junction changes; this is the justification for the term *critical current*. In this regime, it is not possible to have a steady-state solution. Because $\varphi' \propto I-I_c\sin(\varphi)$, we see that $\varphi' >0$, and so the phase constantly advances and a voltage develops over the junction.

The solution to this differential equation can only be obtained numerically, but its general character can be understood as follows. When $\varphi=n\pi$, all of the current flows through the resistor and the voltage is equal to $IR$. For $\varphi\in(0,\pi)$, supercurrent flows to the right through the JJ and so less current flows through the resistor, leading to a smaller voltage and a slower advancement of the phase. On the other hand, for $\varphi\in(\pi,2\pi)$, supercurrent flows to the *left* through the JJ and so *more* current flows through the resistor, leading to a *larger* voltage and a *faster* advancement of the phase.

The key insight is that the RSJ spends a longer time in the voltage-reduced, $\varphi\in(0,\pi)$ region than it does in the voltage-enhanced, $\varphi\in(\pi,2\pi)$ region. The time-average voltage can be computed exactly via evaluation of a somewhat tricky integral, and it turns out that
$$\langle V \rangle = \frac{1}{R}\sqrt{I^2-I_c^2}$$

---

**The DC SQUID**

Armed with an understanding of how a single RSJ works, we can put two of them in parallel to form a SQUID.

[image]

Assuming identical RSJ's, the relevant equations are

$$I = \frac{2V}{R} + I_c\sin(\varphi_1) + I_c\sin(\varphi_2)$$
$$\varphi_1' = \varphi_2' = \frac{2eV}{\hbar}$$
$$J = \frac{1}{2}\big(I_c\sin(\varphi_1)-I_c\sin(\varphi_2)\big)=2\pi n, \qquad n\in \mathbb Z$$
$$\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 +2\pi \frac{\Phi_B - LJ}{\Phi_0}$$

where $J$ is the current circulating through the loop, $\Phi_B$ is the magnetic flux through the loop, $L$ is the SQUID's self-inductance, and $\Phi_0 \equiv 2e/h$ is the magnetic flux quantum. The situation is simplified considerably if we take $L=0$, in which case the only equation we need is

$$I = \frac{2V}{R} + I_c\sin(\varphi_1) + I_c\sin(\varphi_1+\Omega), \qquad \Omega \equiv 2\pi\Phi_B/\Phi_0$$
Employing the angle-addition formula on the second $\sin$ function and doing some more algebra, we finally obtain
$$I = \frac{2V}{R} + I_c \sqrt{2\big(1+\cos(\Omega)\big)}\sin(\varphi_1 + \delta) \equiv \frac{2V}{R}+I_c|\cos(\Omega/2)|\sin(\varphi_1)$$
where
$$\tan(\delta) = \frac{\sin(\Omega)}{1+\cos(\Omega)}$$

But apart from a phase shift, this is just the equation for a *single* RSJ with resistance $R/2$ and critical current $I_c|\cos(\Omega/2)|$. In particular, the time-average voltage across the SQUID is given by

$$\langle V\rangle = \frac{R}{2}\sqrt{I^2-I_c^2\cos^2(\Omega/2)}$$
If we increase $\Phi_B$, $\langle V\rangle$ oscillates between $IR/2$ and $\frac{R}{2}\sqrt{I^2-I_c^2}$ with a period of $\Phi_B$.

The takeaway is that if we operate the SQUID with a current bias $I>2I_c$, the steady-state voltage which develops is periodic in the magnetic flux through the SQUID with a period of $\Phi_B \approx 2\times 10^{-15}$ Wb, making it a *phenomenally* sensitive detector of magnetic flux.

To conclude - what *physically* is happening to make this work?  When $\Phi_B=0$, the JJ's are "in-phase" (in the sense that $\Omega=0$) and they work just like two RSJs in parallel - by which I mean that exactly $I/2$ flows through each $RSJ$, trading off between the resistive and superconducting paths. This leads to a time-average voltage which is *less* than $IR/2$ because the RSJ's spend longer in the low-voltage region than in the high-voltage region.

However, as we thread flux through the loop the RSJ's grow out-of-phase. As $\Omega$ approaches $\pi$, the supercurrents cancel one another out. The supercurrent flowing to the right through one JJ simply flows to the left through the other, while a steady current of $I/2$ flows through each resistor. Because the voltage is no longer oscillating, the time average is simply $IR/2$.